# Django app returns "class object" in admin listing

Tags: django, admin

just like image attached, I have created an app called Term which works perfectly fine, i have also built admin for this app,

My problem has started since I've added new entry in my admin which only appears in my entry listing, I have no idea why this is appearing as Term Object rather than Word or entry name (Where I have highlighted on screen).

Can you please help me finding out why this is happening?

This is my model:

```
from django.db import models

publish_choices = (
        ('0', 'No'),
        ('1', 'Yes'),
    )

class Term(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    date_added = models.DateField()
    definition = models.TextField()
    searches = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    publish = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=publish_choices)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.word
```

and this is my admin

```
from dictionary.models import Term
from django.contrib import admin

admin.site.register(Term)
```

Comment: I fixed some really bad-looking indentation, make sure it's not in your original code.

Comment: What do you mean? I checked indentations and they are all ok

Answer (score 0):

What version of python and django are you using? Try changing unicode to str

Answer (score 0):

if you have read the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/) in detail,
you wiil find the guarantee as follow:

```
__str__() (Python 3)     
Python 3 equivalent of __unicode__().
__unicode__() (Python 2)
A Python “magic method” that returns a unicode “representation” of any object. This is   
what Python and Django will use whenever a model instance needs to be coerced and displayed as a plain string. Most notably, this happens when you display an object in aninteractive console or in the admin.
You’ll always want to define this method; the default isn’t very helpful at all.
```

i guess that you are using python3.3, so you should use **str** to replace the **uncode** method